# Custom view google calendar Api

Tags: google-calendar-api, timetable

Is it possible to show google calendar Api custom view for example : morning,afternoon,evening rather than hours?
I want to use google calendar to create a planning table that show planning of all Employee Work Schedule so it's a Multi Calendar
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google calendar API returns the data from Google calendar.     let's say you have an event on your Google calendar.   you can make a events.list request and the API will return a json data set containg the information about the events on the calendar.

the data is returned in raw json format not as a custom view any formatting of the data will need to be done by your application.